# How to do word wrapping for the content search web part?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I am working on one of the Projects (office 365/Sharepoint online)and I have a three page layout. In the left zone, I have a content search web part which shows Documents that were recently worked/updated. The left zone has been assigned about 17.5% in percentage measure. But if the document name appearing in that web part is quite long than the left zone expands percentage on its own to accommodate the document name. Is there a way to do word-wrapping for the document name appearing there? I am using a customized display template to display the documents inside the web part. Can any CSS be leveraged here for word wrapping?  not sure. If anyone knows, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use developer tool to check element CSS and overwrite the CSS with

```
word-wrap:break-word !important;
width:proper value px
```

Sample test result:

[image]

Comment: one question I have is, I do have a custom display template to display these Documents in the recent documents web part, so would it be better to make this change in the template itself?